# IF statement to determine if a WHERE clause should take place SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where there is a column in a table called 'Type'. In type, it could be BA, AB, or three other two combination varchars in addition to null. I am only concerned with BA or AB.

My problem is filtering this on the where clause, because in the stored proc, I need to make it to where it will be filtered by what is passed in for @Type. So they could pass in BA, AB, or 'either' so the where clause is going to be looking for the appropriate match. **(Currently there is no where clause, I need to add it)**.

Here is the thing, if I do :

```
WHERE Type = @Type
```

That will be great for if they pass in 'BA' or 'AB' but how would I handle if they want *either, including null* (a.k.a. the stored proc should run just as it always has).

I was wondering if it is possible to a do a IF around the where:

```
(psuedocode)
IF @type = ' BA' or 'AB' Then WHERE Type = @ Type
ELSE -no where clause is needed, do what the stored proc has always done
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How does your input look when the user passes in 'either'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE (@type IS NULL OR type = @type)
...
```

If you pass `@type` as `null`, the procedure will run as always.

Comment: @J-MANMORGAN Glad to help. Please don't forget to mark as answer or comment if you have any further question. =)

Comment: I was just waiting for the time limit to expire :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to put an if "around" a where, but consider:

```
WHERE type = @type     -- when @type != NULL, match it
   OR @type IS NULL    -- but if @type is NULL, then match everything
```

For more complex cases the [CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the CASE, didnt think of its use in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WHERE (@Type IN ('AB','BA') AND [Type] = @Type) 
OR @Type IS NULL 
OR @Type NOT IN ('AB','BA')
```