# How to pass dynamically created filters as parameter of stored procedure in SQL Server and filter data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, sql-function

How can I pass some **dynamic filters** (populated from my table `tblMarketingCampaignFilters` in SQL Server) and compare them to a `TargetColumn` in `tblMarketingUsers`?

Just to clarify, I have all the code to generate and populate the filters with the `InputTypes` assigned (it can be numbers, dates, strings, or boolean with checkboxes, only), but the *page* is supposed to Add as much a user wants (*n* filters).

Here is an image showing how my tables are defined

[image: tables used]

I must compare the *filters*, with *columns* (to be added) in `tblMarketingUsers`.

Examples:

- *LastLoginDate* > '20150701' if it is a Date,
- *Advanced Profile Status* > 50(percent) if it is a number,
- *InBothSystems* = 0 if it is a checkbox checked

This is my filter part of the form in the *page*

[image: client-side part]

By now, I have only 4 filters, it could be 10, I don't know.

Thanks.

PS: I think that I am missing a `TableTarget` in `tblMarketingCampaignFilters`, if the system have to look on another table, not only `tblMarketingUsers`, but it doesn't matter so much.

PS2: I am considering passing the filters as text, with the comma-separated style, and then insert this into `transMarketingCampaignFilters`, but still don't know how to *compare* them dynamically, my boss says *"use cursors in SQL"*

**EDIT**

Thanks for the replies, and comments.

This is an approach of what I am thinking to do. I will need to add *Operator* column in **tblMarketingCampaignFilters** (it will store something like : '**=**' , '**<**', '**>**', '**LIKE**') , and btw, this stored procedure will assume that a Campaign with the filters has already submitted on the form, and all data is stored on **transMarketingCampaignFilters**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MarketingUsersGetFiltered
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @CampaignId int,
    @Debug BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @sql varchar(max) = '', @Nsql nvarchar(max), @DatabaseId INT;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
```

`set @DatabaseId = (SELECT DatabaseId from tblMarketingCampaigns where Id=@CampaignId);
select @sql +=  ' AND '+quotename(f.TargetColumn) + f.Operator + 
            case f.InputType 
            when 'int' then cast(cf.Value as int)
            else quotename(cf.Value,'''')               
            end
from dbo.transMarketingCampaignFilters as cf
join dbo.tblMarketingCampaignFilters as f
on cf.CampaignFilterId = f.Id
where cf.CampaignId = @CampaignId

 set @sql = '
 select MarketingUserId,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        Email,
        CompanyId
 from dbo.tblMarketingUsers 
 where DatabaseId = @DatabaseId
 '+ @sql+'
 OPTION (RECOMPILE)';

if @Debug = 1 print @sql;
set @sql = @Nsql;
exec sys.sp_executesql @Nsql,N'@DatabaseId INT',@DatabaseId;

END
GO`

Comment: Tell your boss: ***NO!*** Avoid cursors at all costs in SQL Server !!

Comment: If you have a fixed amount of possible parameters you can have one for each in your procedure. All with NULL default. If not supplied, deal with them in your query with myField = ISNULL(@parameterFilter,myField).(avoiding any CURSORS)

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the stored proc you are talking about?  I can only kinda get what you want with just the pictures.

Comment: I've answered pretty much same question like a week ago. Please give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451870/stored-procedure-not-returning-filtered-results-when-using-null-to-ignore-parame/31452402#31452402

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I can't use your code, because we need that all of the code in C# and Javascript be dynamic too. That will make "slow down" the process of coding (I'm sorry about my English, Argentinian guy here!  ). So, I cannot provide such quantity of parameters in the answer you provided on the other question. It could be a user-defined type, or  an XML parameter like PhillipH said in his answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've written **Javascript** code (a little complex) to :

- Create dynamic filters and its respective inputs

  1. My actual types are only 4 (int,bit,varchar,date)
  2. For 'int' create dynamically an `<input type="number">`
  3. For 'date' create dynamically an `<input type="text">` , with a date plugin
  4. Etc...
- I've created an array to store the id's of my filters and send to the server via AJAX call (and the complete form)

Then in the server code (**C#**) I've written code to:

- Save the campaign details.
- Loop over the parameter array.

  1. Save each filter added with the CampaignId provided by the AddCampaign stored procedure (after save the campaign), the filter id provided by each **select** value of the form, and the value provided on the generated input.

And then in **SQL Server**, I've just used the stored procedure that I've supplied on the question, a little modified:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_MarketingUsersGetFiltered
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@CampaignId int,
@Debug BIT = 0
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @sql varchar(max) = '', @Nsql nvarchar(max), @DatabaseId INT;
-- Insert statements for procedure here

set @DatabaseId = (SELECT DatabaseId from tblMarketingCampaigns where Id=@CampaignId);
select @sql +=  ' AND '+quotename(f.TargetColumn) + f.Operation + 
            case f.InputType 
            when 'int' then cf.Value
            when 'bit' then cf.Value
            else quotename(cf.Value,'''')               
            end
from dbo.transMarketingCampaignFilters as cf
join dbo.tblMarketingCampaignFilters as f
on cf.CampaignFilterId = f.Id
where cf.CampaignId = @CampaignId

 set @sql = '
 select MarketingUserId,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        tblMarketingUsers.Email as UserEmail,
        CompanyId,
        CompanyName,
        Address1,
        Address2,
        City,
        SmartInsightProfile,
        LastLoginDate,
        AdvancedProfileStatus
 from dbo.tblMarketingUsers 
 left join dbo.tblCompanies on tblMarketingUsers.CompanyId=tblCompanies.Id
 where DatabaseId = @DatabaseId
 '+ @sql+'
 OPTION (RECOMPILE)';

if @Debug = 1 print @sql;
set @Nsql = @sql;
exec sys.sp_executesql @Nsql,N'@DatabaseId INT',@DatabaseId;

END
GO
```

My tables are something like this

[image: Tables]

Where tblMarketingCampaignFilters stores rows similar to :

**(Id ,  Name ,    InputType ,TargetColumn ,Operator)**

**(1, 'Advanced Profile Status',  'int', 'AdvancedProfileStatus', '<')**

**(2, 'Last Login Date',  'date', 'LastLoginDate', '<')**

**(3, 'Geo Location (City)',  'varchar', 'City', 'LIKE')**

and the final result :

```
 select MarketingUserId,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        tblMarketingUsers.Email as UserEmail,
        CompanyId,
        CompanyName,
        Address1,
        Address2,
        City,
        SmartInsightProfile,
        LastLoginDate,
        AdvancedProfileStatus
 from dbo.tblMarketingUsers 
 left join dbo.tblCompanies on tblMarketingUsers.CompanyId=tblCompanies.Id
 where DatabaseId = 3
  AND [City]LIKE'%salta%' AND [SmartInsightProfile]!=1 AND [LastLoginDate]<'20150708' AND [AdvancedProfileStatus]<42
 OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Thank you very much for the help!

I know that this is not the BEST way, but it works for me now!

Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

1) Pass through the filter data as a user-defined type, or as an XML parameter, into the stored procedure.

2) Examine the content of the flexible parameter-set in the stored procedure and for the most common use-cases call subsidiary stored procedures with fixed SQL content which satisfy the most common cases. This allows those procedures to be optimal for their purpose.

3) Where the filter set does not match any high frequency predicted pattern use dynamically generated SQL where-clauses inside the stored procedure layer to generate a match.

It is tempting to generate parameterised SQL in the business logic tier and execute it against SQL Server for all cases, and this might be your best approach if you cannot identify any very frequent use-cases, but its lacks the test-ability and east performance optimisation of the branching described in (2).

Comment: I like point (1) . And I think that (2) is solved by the column _InputType_ of the tblMarketingCampaignFilter table. But like I said on my edited question, I will have to add a _TypeOp_ or _Operator_ column too. So, if anyone is adding one more filter, they will have to point a TargetColumn, select an Operator and a Type for the new Filter. And (3) is to me particularly similar to 2, and if you could check the stored procedure that I'm making it will be GREAT!

Comment: You are taking a good approach in your sample stored proc, however I would pass through the set of "Fields",  "Operators" and "Values" in a Table variable based on a user-defined Type, then you loop through all the rows in the table building up your SQL WHERE clause, then finally add it onto the SELECT. You might want to re-consider whether it would be more test-able to do all this as Dynamic SQL in C# (there will be no difference in performance between dynamic SQL and Stored Procs these days).

Comment: Thanks! I will test that, and tell You what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the possible filters as search parameters in the stored procedure. If the filter is set, the parameter will be not null, otherwise it will be null. Then, in the where clause you only use the parameter if it is not null. Something like this:

```
WHERE (@LastLoginDate IS NULL OR t.LoginDate<@LastLoginDate) AND
      (@CityId IS NULL OR t.CityId=@CityId)
```

Comment: This will work - however a lot of `OR` statements are going to kill performance.

Comment: I can't use this, because we need that all of the code in C# and Javascript be dynamic too. This will make slow down the process of coding(they will need to pay us more, obviously :) ) if any new Filter is added. Please see my update. Thanks !

Comment: OR will not kill the performance because you are evaluating the value of a parameter without hitting the database. Indexes in the database are gonna be used as normal. Another option is to create a dynamic query and only add a where condition when the parameter is not null but dynamic queries are harder to write and debut. On the other, the SP has to be updated anyway when you change the front-end of the app. If you add a filter you need to change the SP, review index usages, perfofrmance, etc.

Comment: OR will have an effect on performance - the query plan will be compiled based on the path used for your first pass - if that path does not use the index because you happen to pass NULL as your parameter, it will then not use the index even if you pass a non NULL. Also, the assumption is that SQL Server does Boolean op short-circuiting - see http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/ for why this is not a good assumption.